# convert dataframe in python to json or dictionary type object

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame like

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1' :['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C'], 'col2': ['13','15','17','11','15','12','21','23'], 'col3' : [3,5,8,7,2,5,1,3]},columns= ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

print(data)

  col1 col2  col3
0    A   13     3
1    A   15     5
2    A   17     8
3    B   11     7
4    B   15     2
5    C   12     5
6    C   21     1
7    C   23     3
```

I want to convert this dataframe into like

```
[{"A": {"col2": ["13": 3,"15": 5,"17": 8]},"B": {"col2": ["11": 7,"15": 2]},"C": {"col2": ["12": 5,"21": 1,"23": 3]}}]
```

I tried using groupby by 'col1' then converting last two columns into dictionary
but it not getting desired result.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to bite the bullet and use a lambda with a groupby statement.

Note lambda's aren't very efficient and this doesn't really seem like a logical / proper json structure.

but to answer your question.

```
data.groupby('col1')\
         .apply(lambda x : {'col2' : dict(zip(x['col2'],x['col3']))}).to_dict()


{'A': {'col2': {'13': 3, '15': 5, '17': 8}},
 'B': {'col2': {'11': 7, '15': 2}},
 'C': {'col2': {'12': 5, '21': 1, '23': 3}}}
```